# Reference a cell in excel to the content of an external text file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to reference a cell in Excel to the content of an external text file.

I have this file `c:\calc.text` which just have a number inside.
I want to put number inside the `calc.txt` inside a cell of an excel file by formula.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer : it is not possible to accomplish this in a formula with "standard" Excel.
Some alternatives:

- The most basic is to manually import (but this you probably know already)
- Use VBA to import the txt file data into a cell in your worksheet
- Use Microsoft Power Query for Excel, a free add-in (has been renamed "Get and Transform" in Excel 2016

Based on your question, I would recommend the last option: powerful, and you can use this straight into formulas.